# Proteger páginas que são carregadas dentro do template - Kohana

Tags: php, kohana

Estou fazendo um admin aqui que carrega no miolo as respectivas páginas. Sei como permitir que sejam acessadas somente após o login, mas não sei se da maneira que estou fazendo é o modo correto. Vejam o Template:

```
class Controller_Administracao extends Controller_Template {
        //put your code here
        public $template = 'template_admin';

        public function before() {
            parent::before();
            if($this->auto_render){
                $this->template->content = '';
            }
        }
        public function after() {
            parent::after();

        }
    }
```

Até ai tudo bem, aqui eu chamo a *action* e faço a "proteção" dela:

```
public function action_home(){
            //Aqui uso o Auth do Kohana, está tudo normal
            //Se não estiver feito o login, volta para a tela inicial
            $user = Auth::instance()->get_user();
            if(!$user){
                $this->redirect('/');
            }
            //Feito o login, vai para o Dashboard
            else{
                $this->template->content = View::factory('admin/default');
            }
        }
```

A minha dúvida é: Eu preciso verificar com o `Auth::instance()->get_user()` em todas as *actions* que vão ser chamadas dentro do template ou tem alguma forma de proteger todas as *actions* sem precisar ficar fazendo essa verificação? Existe a possibilidade de fazer isso no próprio template?

Answer (score 1):

Já tive contato muito superficial com o *Kohana*, não conheço os detalhes, mas de forma *genérica* baseado no modelo [*MVC*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVC), posso fazer algumas considerações que podem ajudar.

> Existe a possibilidade de fazer isso no próprio template

Se você tem um sistema que possui login, quando o usuário for acessar - alterar seus dados, o controller validará a sessão e vai decidir a ação que será executada.

1 . Quando o user estiver conectado e acessar o perfil, serão exibidos os dados pessoais.
2 . Caso a sessão não seja validada, o controller vai capturar e executar um redirecionamento para a tela de login ou simplesmente carregar o formulário de login.

Veja que isso é uma responsabilidade *exclusiva* do *controller*. Manter qualquer tipo de controle de acesso ou validação de dados na *view* é um erro.

---

> A minha dúvida é: Eu preciso verificar com o `Auth::instance()->get_user()` em todas as actions que vão ser chamadas dentro do template ou tem alguma forma de proteger todas as actions sem precisar ficar fazendo essa verificação?

Se todos os métodos do seu *Controller_Administracao* precisam ser validados, você deve usar o método `before` que será executado ANTES do método invocado.

```
public function before() {
     parent::before();

     // template definido
     $this->template->content = View::factory('admin/default');

     // usuário não identificado - executa o redirecionamento
     if( ! $user ){
        $this->redirect('/');
     }
}
```

---

Note que não vou entrar nos detalhes próprios do Kohana por não conhecer tão bem, mas o método *before* é o que você precisa para não repetir a mesma verificação de autenticidade em todos os outros métodos do seu controller.